# How to convert 32 bit integers to 32 bit floats so that the ordering is preserved?

Tags: c++

I have two 32 bit integers i1,i2 which I need to convert to floats f1,f2 in such a way that their relative ordering is preserved (i.e. i1 < i2 => f1 < f2)

Will a reinterpret_cast do the trick? Is there some better way?

Comment: Do the floating point values need to mean anything?

Comment: what is your problem with just assigning the integer to a float, why doesnt that work for you?

Comment: This question has deceptive qualities, as GregC points out. I did not at first think that the int could have increments too small to represent in a float, but how would 2,147,483,647 and 2,147,483,646 work? would both become 2,147,483 * 10^3 or?

Comment: The values don't need to mean anything (beyond their ordering being the same). The integers are large enough that simply converting will not work. I cannot use doubles

Comment: Integer inherently stores more information in the same bit width than a float on a 32-bit machine, because of values that are reserved for NaN space and infinities.  So in short, cannot be done.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: `float` only has 24 bits of precision, so two large integers can both yield the same `float` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the integer values are less than 2<sup>24</sup>, just convert the values:

```
float f1 = i1, f2 = i2;
```

For larger values, you will lose precision and two distinct integers may convert to the same floating point value.

On the other hand, you could copy the bit pattern. If your floats are IEEE754, then this requires that the sign bits agree and that neither integer represents some form of `NaN`. (If the sign bits do not agree, you must beware of `-0.f == +0.f:`.) To copy the binary representation:

```
float f1;
std::copy(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&i1),
          reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&i1) + 4,
          reinterpret_cast<char*>(&f1));
```

Answer (score 3):

Integer inherently stores more information in the same bit width than a float on a 32-bit machine, because of values that are reserved for NaN space and infinities. So in short, cannot be done.

int range: -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
float precision: 7 digits

I think that it would be possible if the nature of the problem limits the range of integer values somehow.  Otherwise use a double-precision value.  It has 15-16 digits in mantissa.

Keep in mind that in C++ the int type can have different range depending on your native pointer size.  On a 16-bit machine, int range is -32k to +32k.

Also, keep in mind that there's no promise of correctness for two (binary) least-significant bits, even in a cast-to-float scenario.

http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html

Answer (score 1):

When you're casting a `int` to a `float` the value is not changed in general, therefore the relative order is preserved.

The `reinterpret_cast` cannot be used for this purpose, since it is only usable for pointers, e. g. converting an object to a kind of "flat" memory representation, i. e. it copies the *bit pattern*.